# How to solve "Error: (converted from warning) Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"?

Tags: fedora, r

I am trying to install a library in R and I have a this message

```
Error: (converted from warning) Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
```

What I saw is some solutions but for mac User, like this one

Type in your terminal

```
system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")
```

But I am working in a server with FEDORA an this is not working for me, any help will be awesome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a server. Our support said I should try the command:

```
echo $LC_CTYPE
```

The system returned `UTF-8` where it should return nothing.

The solution for me was to use the following command:

```
unset LC_CTYPE
```